# Combine "count" results of several queries into a single table

Tags: count, union-all

Currently using this query:

```
select "tablename1", count(*) as Count from table1
UNION ALL
select "tablename2", count(field2) as Count from table2
```

It gives the desired result: table names in column 1 and their respective counts in column 2.

It has the undesirable side effect, though, of having the word "tablename1" as the heading for column 1. (It has "Count" for the heading of column 2, which is what I wanted).

Edit: output looks like this:

```
tablename1 Count
---------- -----
tablename1 1000
tablename2 2000
```

Is there a way to manually set the heading for column 1 to be something like "Table name" instead of the actual name of tablename1?

It has to be something really obvious that I'm missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just use alias for the column name:

```
select "tablename1" as TableName, count(*) as Count from table1
UNION ALL
select "tablename2" as TableName, count(field2) as Count from table2
```

Output:

```
TableName Count
---------- -----
tablename1 1000
tablename2 2000
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, @Liero. I could not get the "comment" to format properly, so I responded below.

Comment: Try again with updated answer.

Comment: Same error. I am using Databricks SQL if that matters. Those are all single quotes, right?

Comment: Update: I removed the single quotes from around 'Table name' and changed it to a single word, Tablename. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, Databricks has slighly different syntax. I updated my answer. If it solved your issue, accept it, or write your own answer. Thanks